# How can I create new variables in a loop, with the names and values coming from a list?

Tags: python, list, variables

How can I create new variables with the names and values coming from a list?

This:

```
name = ['mike', 'john', 'steve']   
age = [20, 32, 19]  
index = 0

for e in name:
    name[index] = age[index]
    index = index+1
```

...of course does not work. What should I do?

I want to do this:

```
print mike
>>> 20

print steve
>>> 19
```

Comment: [You should keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)  Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Strongly agree with Sven. Don't do this. If you think you have an exceptionally good reason then (a) you probably don't but (b) tell us what it is just in case. (It can be done, but I urge anyone reading this not to explain how unless the OP has given a good enough reason.)

Comment: Well, i have a lot of widgets in pygtk (from glade), named: entry_name, entry_secondname, entry_age etc. Normally i import it like this:
`self.entry_name = self.wTree.get_widget("entry_name")`
`self.entry_secondname = self.wTree.get_widget("entry_secondname")`

But i wanted to automatized it in loop. Wrong way?

Comment: @user1496868: If it's `self`, then you can assign to `self.__dict__[somename]` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `dictionaries` are more suitable for this purpose:

```
>>> name = ['mike', 'john', 'steve']   

>>> age = [20, 32, 19] 

>>> dic=dict(zip(name, age))

>>> dic['mike']
20
>>> dic['john']
32
```

But if you still want to create variables on the fly you can use `globals()[]`:

```
>>> for x,y in zip(name, age):
    globals()[x] = y


>>> mike
20
>>> steve
19
>>> john
32
```

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use `globals()`:

```
globals()[e] = age[index]
```

Generally, though, you don't want to do that; a dictionary is much more convenient.

```
people = {
    'mike': 20,
    'john': 32,
    'steve': 19
}
```

Comment: No, you can't use `vars()`.  See the documentation.  It returns `locals()`, and the return value of `locals()` must not be modified.  (It will work by chance if `locals()` happens to coincide with `globals()`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oops, thanks. It is now "fixed". Not that I recommend it anyways.

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is the way to go!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as dr

# Get data for this year, so far
start = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019,6,1)

companies = ['AA', 'AAPL', 'BA', 'IBM']
df_dict = {}
for name in companies:
    df_dict[name] = pd.DataFrame()
    df_dict[name] = dr.data.get_data_yahoo(name, start, end)

print()
print(' Apple dataframe ')
print(df_dict['AAPL'].head())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
name = ['mike', 'john', 'steve']   
age = [20, 32, 19] 
for i in range(len(name)):
    exec("%s = %d" %(name[i], age[i]))
print(mike)
print(john)
print(steve)
```

Comment: Please give some information about what your code does.

Comment: Can you make this work for values that are strings - eg, suppose age was ['Twenty', 'Thirty two', 'Nineteen']

Comment: This is a poor solution, playing into OP's [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's OK to add this purely for completeness, but one must state the caveat that 99.9% of the time, this is not desirable. Such a caveat is not present here.