# How could a list of names be used to instantiate variables using a class?

Tags: python, class, loops, global, instantiation

Warning: This question isn't a duplicate of the old ["How do I create a bunch of variables in a loop?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319909/creating-new-variables-in-loop-with-names-from-list-in-python) because it uses a special class with arguments. If code actively disrespectful to PEP8 makes your eyes bleed, go no further, traveler!

Ok, I'm writing some code for a graph of objects in a detailed network and I want the code itself to look a particular way. For the purposes of this question, this means that I do not want to write the code such that I am referencing a dictionary with keys generated in a loop that reference instances of my special class. I want to write the code in a minimal way that I am aware is non-Pythonic, yet acceptable to my awful psychological makeup.

So: how should the code for the function `instantiate` shown below be written? The idea is that this function instantiates a variable with the name specified using the special class `Relay` that has some arguments.

```
import uuid

def generate_Python_variable_names(
    number = 10
    ):

    names = []
    while len(names) < number:
        name = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")
        if name[0].isalpha():
            names.append(name)

    return names

number_relays = 100

for name in generate_Python_variable_names(number = number_relays):
    instantiate(name, Relay(configuration = 1)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Relay` class? Is it the value of the variable.

Comment: What does `Relay` do in your example? Is `Relay(configuration=1)` just the value that the variable will hold?

Comment: Add the `key=name, value=Relay (1)` to the `globals()` dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption that you are at module level. And what you want is to create new variables in the current module.

To do this, you can use the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#globals) function to have access to the module's variables.

```
for name in generate_Python_variable_names(number=number_relays):
    obj = globals()
    obj[name] = Relay(configuration=1)
```

If you print the variables, you will get something like this:

```
{'Relay': <class '__main__.Relay'>,
 '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': 'path/to/your/module.py',
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 'df55cd5884924e88a4a13371b248d755': <__main__.Relay object at 0x105f66fd0>,
 'e11d3a1e3afb4ada801e08d57219e9be': <__main__.Relay object at 0x105f66550>,
 ...
 'ef93466af4a34e7b8ec28568cca664f5': <__main__.Relay object at 0x105f66ed0>,
 'generate_Python_variable_names': <function generate_Python_variable_names at 0x105f670c8>,
 'name': 'ef93466af4a34e7b8ec28568cca664f5',
 'number_relays': 100,
 'obj': <Recursion on dict with id=4394090856>,
 'uuid': <module 'uuid' from 'path/to/uuid.pyc'>}
```

As you can see, you have one hundred of new variables in your module.