# how do I make empty lists based on a number of input information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am creating a code where I ask users to give certain information. Based on the number of input items, I want to create empty lists that will be used for a for-loop later on.

For instance,

```
user_info=[19,20,21,22,23]
```

Desired output:

```
19=[], 20=[], 21=[], 22=[], 23=[]
```

Since the first letter couldn't be number, I wouldn't care if the list name is alphabets.

```
a=[],b=[],c=[],d=[],e=[]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be a *lot* more specific here. This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) at best; dynamically creating a bunch of named variables is a terrible idea. It's conceivable making a `list` of `list`s or a `dict` of `list`s might make sense, but not named variables.

Comment: As a compromise, as @ShadowRanger mentioned, the dict with values as empty lists would be a good first approach : `{info: [] for info in user_info}`

Comment: I suspect this qualifies as a duplicate of [Creating new variables in loop, with names from list, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11319909/364696).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but you can use a dictionary:

```
vars = {}

for i in range(num_inputs):
    vars[i+1] = []
```

To access your variables, you'd use the dictionary:

```
vars[23] += [42, 34, 92]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it well, u can simply make a dictionary for every input. As long as you don't enter equal numbers, it will work.

For example, if you have the list:

```
user_info=[19,20,21,22,23]
```

You can just create a dictionary that would be like :

```
myDictionary = {19:[],20:[],21:[],22:[],23:[]}
```

And you can acces to each array just iterating through your **user_info** array:

```
for users in user_info:
    print(myDictionary.get(users))

[],[],[],[],[]
```